# Polymer post method for iron ajax

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm new to polymer and I've been struggling with the posting using iron-ajax. This is my code

My component:

```
<template>
   <button type="submit" onclick="getPost" class="btn btn-default" id="register-form" style="margin-left: 35%; background-color: #008000; color: black; width: 30%;">Submit</button>
   <iron-ajax
        id="ajax"
        method="POST"
        body='[{"id": "1"}]'
        url ="http://localhost/api/post.php"
        on-response="success"
        lastError="error"
        debounce-duration="3000">
    </iron-ajax>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'register-form',
      getPost:function(){
        this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
      },
      success:function(r){
        alert(r.detail.response);
      },
      error:function(r){
        alert(r.detail.response);
      }
    });
</script>
```

My php file:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    if ($_POST){
        echo $_POST['id'];
    }
?>
```

Initially I wanted the the php to return a json but it kept on returning null.So i decided to change it to that to see if it will return the id I posted but it still returned null.The GET method seems to work fine though. And I've tried the solutions i found on the Internet but it still dint work.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your body attribute like this?

```
body='{"id": "1"}'
```

... if the above doesn't work, then try a computed binding. e.g.

```
body="[[_body()]]"
```

And,

```
_body: function() {
    return {
        id: 1
    };
}
```

Comment: Still returns null.

Comment: Then try a computed binding, https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed

Comment: Use your browser's dev tool to see what is in your POST request body

Comment: Hie. Thank you for that. I fixed it but i'm still not getting my echo. I decided to put an else statement in the php to echo  something different and instead of the id it echoed what was in the else statement. The condition is not true even though the method is set to post

Answer (score 0):

the button's `onclick="getPost"` does not call your component's `getPost`method, replace it with `on-click=...` which is the convention Polymer uses to attach a `click` event listener to the button

Comment: Hie. Thank you for that. I fixed it but i'm still not getting my echo. I decided to put an else statement in the php to echo  something different and instead of the id it echoed what was in the else statement. The condition is not true even though the method is set to post